# Oracle Query Logic Declare and With

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

I want to printout a Dynamic built query. Yet I am stuck at variable declaration; Error At line 2.
I need the maximum size for these VARCHAR2 variables.

Do I have a good overall structure ?

I use the result of the WITH inside the dynamic query.

```
DECLARE l_sql_query VARCHAR2(2000);
        l_sql_queryFinal VARCHAR2(2000);
        
    
with cntp as (select distinct 
cnt.code code_container,
*STUFF*
FROM container cnt

WHERE 

cnt.status !='DESTROYED'
order by cnt.code)

BEGIN
FOR l_counter IN 2022..2032
LOOP
    l_sql_query := l_sql_query || 'SELECT cntp.code_container *STUFF*
FROM cntp 
GROUP BY cntp.code_container ,cntp.label_container, cntp.Plan_Classement, Years
HAVING
cntp.Years=' || l_counter ||'
AND
/*stuff*/ TO_DATE(''31/12/' || l_counter ||''',''DD/MM/YYYY'')
AND SUM(cntp.IsA)=0
AND SUM(cntp.IsB)=0

UNION
';

END LOOP;
END;

l_sql_queryFinal := SUBSTR(l_sql_query,  0,  LENGTH (l_sql_query) – 5);
l_sql_queryFinal := l_sql_queryFinal||';'

dbms_output.put_line(l_sql_queryFinal);
```

Comment: Which error did you exactly get (its error code and original Oracle message, not using your own words). What is MAX_STRING_SIZE? You should - I believe - put some *numeric* value in there, e.g. VARCHAR2(1000).

Comment: @Littlefoot I did put 2000 in it, i still have "error starting at line : 2 of the command...."

Comment: I'm not sure what your `with` is supposed to be doing, but it should be part of a SQL query, but a PL/SQL block - it certainly doesn't belong immediately before `begin`. Maybe you meant it to be part of the dynamic query? But I'm also not sure why you're using dynamic SQL or creating mots of unions - it looks like you can just do a single static query, since you're already aggregating by year? (Your code seems to error on line 5, not line 2, when it hits the the `with`...)

Comment: @AlexPoole It is a big query, I need to first store the result of the with and then I can do my multiple union on it.

Comment: I'm not convinced you need the unions when you are aggregating anyway, but I'm not sure how the `disposition_date` (which is a string?!) fits in - that's something you might want to look at again, but isn't really relevant to this question.

Comment: I cannot fully explain the purpose of the query ^^ I needed the good structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted has quite a few issues, among them:

- you've got the `with` (CTE) as a standlone fragment in the declare section, which isn't valid. If you want it to be part of the dynamic string then put it in the string;
- your `END;` is in the wrong place;
- you have `–` instead of `-`;
- you remove the last 5 characters, but you end with a new line, so you need to remove 6 to include the U of the last UNION;
- the line that appens a semicolon is itself missing one (though for dynamic SQL you usually don't want a semicolon, so the whole line can probably be removed);
- 2000 characters is too small for your example, but it's OK with the actual maximum of 32767.

```
DECLARE
  l_sql_query VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_sql_queryFinal VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  -- initial SQL which just declares the CTE
  l_sql_query := q'^
with cntp as (select distinct 
cnt.code code_container,
*STUFF*
FROM container cnt

WHERE 

cnt.status !='DESTROYED'
order by cnt.code)

^';

  -- loop around each year...
  FOR l_counter IN 2022..2032
  LOOP
    l_sql_query := l_sql_query || 'SELECT cntp.code_container *STUFF*
FROM cntp 
GROUP BY cntp.code_container ,cntp.label_container, cntp.Plan_Classement, Years
HAVING
cntp.Years=' || l_counter ||'
AND
MAX(TO_DATE(cntp.DISPOSITION_DATE,''DD/MM/YYYY'')) BETWEEN TO_DATE(''01/01/'|| l_counter ||''',''DD/MM/YYYY'') AND TO_DATE(''31/12/' || l_counter ||''',''DD/MM/YYYY'')
AND SUM(cntp.IsA)=0
AND SUM(cntp.IsB)=0

UNION
';

  END LOOP;

  l_sql_queryFinal := SUBSTR(l_sql_query,  0,  LENGTH (l_sql_query) - 6);
  l_sql_queryFinal := l_sql_queryFinal||';';

  dbms_output.put_line(l_sql_queryFinal);
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1f3f0acd07dcdcb7292963abbe4a3111)

The `q[^...^]` in the first assignment is [the alternative quoting mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA), which means you don't have to escape (by doubling-up) the quotes within that string, around `'DESTYORED'`. Notice the `^` delimiters do not appear in the final generated query.

Whether the generated query actually does what you want is another matter... The `cntp.Years=` part should probably be in a `where` clause, not `having`; and you might be able to simplify this to a single query instead of lots of unions, as you're already aggregating. All of that is a bit beyond the scope of your question though.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: just I needed to create another string for the with and then concat it with the l_queryFInal.

Comment: OK... I don't see why you *need* to do that, but it's certainly a valid option.

Comment: To put the result of your query in a textfile, simply putting what you wrote minus "/" inside a spool + "execute immediate l_sql_queryFinal;"  is enough ?

Comment: You don't really put something inside a spool, and you need the `/` to make it run - well, depending on the client/tool you're using. In SQL\*Plus you could do `set feeback off serveroutput on` followed by `spool some_file` then the query above and then `spool off`. That's separate from `execute immediate`, you don't need a file if that's what you're doing; but as I mentioned you also don't want the final semicolon...

Comment: I dont have access to the database, I had to create the query only from the model and knowledge I have on it. My query needs to work on the first run. I need to export the results, and I apparently takes a lot of time, the text file seems to be quicker.

Comment: I have another error : line 30(starting from l_counter) String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767)

Comment: That error isn't thrown in the fiddle, and I don't really see where it could be coming from. If you've modified this further and introduced a new problem you should really ask a new question about that - but try to debug it yourself first, of course.

Comment: I have a special character in the first string query , inferior or equal : "<=" how to put it in string query ?

Comment: That isn't a special character... I suggest you ask a new question with minimal code to reproduce your new problem.

Comment: That seems to be a problem with db<>fiddle, not the code; it doesn't print anything without the `<=`, and prints that OK if you comment out the loop, or reduce the loop - looks like it's unhappy when the size exceeds 4k but not sure why. I guess it uses a too-small string to retrieve the buffer somewhere, and fails silently. And the whole thing works in SQL Developer.

Comment: Yes,  the final query is too big for a VARCHAR2. I'll work around. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to put the maximum size "automaticcaly" like "VARCHAR2(MAX_STRING_SIZE) does it work ?

No. And no.

The maximum size of `varchar2` in PL/SQL is 32767. If you want to hedge against that changing at some point in the future you can declare [a user-defined subtype](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/datatypes.htm#GUID-FDC366F3-66AA-4F6A-A59B-5A08DCBD4F9F) in a shared package ...

```
create or replace package my_subtypes as

  subtype max_string_size is varchar2(32767);

end my_subtypes;
/
```

... and reference that in your program...

```
DECLARE
  l_sql_query       my_subtypes.max_string_size;
  l_sql_queryFinal  my_subtypes.max_string_size;
...
```

So if Oracle subsequently raises the maximum permitted size of a VARCHAR2 in PL/SQL you need only change the definition of `my_subtypes.max_string_size` for the bounds to be raised wherever you used that subtype.

Alternatively, just use a CLOB. Oracle is pretty clever about treating a CLOB as a VARCHAR2 when its size is <= 32k.

To solve your other problem you need to treat the WITH clause as a string and assign it to your query variable.

```
l_sql_query       my_subtypes.max_string_size := q'[
with cntp as (select distinct 
cnt.code code_container,
*STUFF*
FROM container cnt
WHERE cnt.status !='DESTROYED'
order by cnt.code) ]';
```

Note the use of the special quote syntax `q'[ ... ]'` to avoid the need to escape the quotation marks in your query snippet.

---

> A dynamic string query do not access a temp table ?

Dynamic SQL is a string containing a DML or DDL statement which we execute with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE or DBMS_SQL commands. Otherwise it is  exactly the same as static SQL, it doesn't behave any differently. In fact the best way to write dynamic SQL is to start by writing the static statement in a worksheet, make it correct and then figure out which bits need to be dynamic (variables, placeholders) and which bits remain static (boilerplate). In your case the WITH clause is a static part of the statement.

Comment: thanks for the info, but it seems that the error does not comme from the value I put in VARCHAR2, I tried with 2 000, same error after.

Comment: Is there a way to put the maximum size "automaticcaly" like "VARCHAR2(MAX_STRING_SIZE) does it work ?

Comment: I use the result of the WITH inside the dynamic query. I don't want to make it dynamic, I have edited the post to be more clear.

Comment: I cannot change the subtype max_string_size, or dont event know if it exists.

Comment: Your code is attempting to construct **a single query**. The WITH clause is boilerplate (i.e. not dynamic) but the only way to reference it in the dynamic SQL is to include it in the statement string.

Comment: A dynamic string query do not access a temp table ?

Comment: That subtype is not an Oracle built-in, but something you can declare yourself. I only mentioned it because you were asking. I think the main thrust of your problem is not declaring the WITH clause as a string. If you do that you can just use VARCHAR2(32767) or CLOB, and forget about maximum string sizing.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been pointed out, you seem to have misunderstood what a `with` clause is: it's a clause of a SQL statement, not a procedural declaration. My definition, it must be followed by `select`.

But also, as a general rule, I would recommend avoiding dynamic SQL when possible. In this case, if you can simulate a table with the range of years you want, you can join instead of having to run the same query multiple times.

The easy trick to doing that is to use Oracle's `connect by` syntax to use a recursive query to produce the expected number of rows.

Once you've done that, adding this table as a join pretty trivially:

```
WITH cntp AS
(
                SELECT DISTINCT code code_container,
                                [additional columns]
                FROM            container
                WHERE           status !='DESTROYED') cntc,
(
       SELECT to_date('01/01/'
                     || (LEVEL+2019), 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS start_date,
              to_date('31/12/'
                     || (LEVEL+2019), 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS end_date,
              (LEVEL+2019)                          AS year
       FROM   dual
              CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 11) year_table
SELECT   cntp.code_container,
         [additional columns]
FROM     cntp
join     year_table
ON       cntp.years = year_table.year
GROUP BY [additional columns],
         years,
         year_table.start_date,
         year_table.end_date
HAVING   max(to_date(cntp.disposition_date,''dd/mm/yyyy'')) BETWEEN year_table.start_date AND year_table.end_date
AND      SUM(cntp.isa)=0
AND      SUM(cntp.isb)=0
```

(This query is totally untested and may not actually fulfill your needs; I am providing my best approximation based on the information available.)

Comment: Thanks but could you delete the columns names ? anonymous

Comment: Sure, but there's nothing here that's not in the question.